# C++ using HIToolbox

Tags: c++, macos, macos-carbon

I am having a difficult time linking to the Carbon HIToolbox framework in a (non-cocoa) C++ application. I am able to link to IOKit, Carbon, and ApplicationServices without any problems:

```
... -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework ApplicationServices ...
```

However, I have tried adding HIToolbox as a framework to the linker options:

```
-framework HIToolbox => ld: framework not found HIToolbox
```

Also, suspecting that the library might be part of the Carbon framework itself, I tried declaring an external function from the HIToolbox:

```
extern UInt32 GetDblTime(void); => Undefined symbol...
```

Xcode doesn't seem to be able to find any headers for HIToolbox either.

What am I missing?

Note: I'm using Xcode 5 on OS X 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently HIToolbox has been deprecated and is not available for 64-bit applications.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/944767#944767

Comment: As you answered your own question, I imagine you didn't get much feedback on here about this... how did you ultimately get around this problem (since it's deprecated)?

Comment: @white_rabbit I ended up adding an objective-c (.mm) file to my project and implemented a function there that accesses the cocoa framework to fetch the doubleClickInterval. ``[NSEvent doubleClickInterval]``. C++/Obj-C interoperability works really well.